# Find the locus of the point of intersection of three mutually perpendicular tangent planes to the paraboloid $ax^2+by^2=2cz.$

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-geometry

Find the locus of the point of intersection of three mutually perpendicular tangent planes to the paraboloid $ax^2+by^2=2cz.$

The solution given in a regional handout(or extract) is hereby attached:

[image]

[image]

However, I don't get how are they concluding $l_r^2+m_r^2+n_r^2=1(\forall r\in \{1,2,3\})$ unless $l_r,m_r,n_r$ are direction cosines. This relation is only true if they are direction cosines and hence when they assume equation of the plane as $lx+my+nz=p$, they essentially considered, $l,m,n$ as direction cosines and $p$ as the length of perpendicular from the origin, right? But if this is correct, I dont still get how is $l_1^2+l_2^2+l_3^2=0$ ? When I tried adding equations of all planes, it didn't simplify to the required form, but still how are they getting all those relations about normals of planes?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same doubt but in different concept - [Director Sphere to Ellipsoid](https://socratic.org/questions/show-that-the-path-traced-by-the-point-of-intersection-of-three-mutual-perpendic). You can go through it for a bit more clarity as to what author is doing in your given concept.

After going through it you'll see that the doubt you have is same in both `(which you have written in paragraph)`.

Now coming to your doubt - it's a concept called `3 Mutually Orthogonal Vectors || Orthogonal Matrix  ∈  Vector Spaces`.

We get it by putting mutually orthogonal vectors in Matrix A and using relation

> A . A^T = A^T . A = I

• Do it in terms of < l1, m1, n1 >, <l2, m2, n2>, <l3, m3, n3>.

• You'll get the desired result which author has assumed in your case (i.e. core of your doubt).

• I'll take 2-3 pages to actually get why that results comes.

• Do it once and you'll be set for life. Since it's a trivial concept.

• To shorten it you can take `∑` forms in your matrix product.

You can find it in initial chapters of any book on vector spaces. You can refer [Schaum's Outline](http://www.astronomia.edu.uy/progs/algebra/Linear_Algebra,_4th_Edition__(2009)Lipschutz-Lipson.pdf). You can find your doubt in literal form of a ques in many books on vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Three planes be $l_ix+m_iy+n_iz=p_i\tag*{}$ where $i=1,2,3$.

Putting it in matrix form, we have:
$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}l_1&m_1&n_1\\ l_2&m_2&n_2\\ l_3&m_3&n_3\end{pmatrix}}_{=\mathcal  O}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}p_1\\p_2\\p_3\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$

If they are mutually perpendicular, WLOG, we can assume that:  $\begin{align}&\Omega(i,j)\\&:=\left(l_i\mathbf{\hat{i}}+m_i\mathbf{\hat{j}}+n_i\mathbf{\hat k}\right)\mathbf{\cdot}\left(l_j\mathbf{\hat{i}}+m_j\mathbf{\hat{j}}+n_j\mathbf{\hat k}\right)\\&=l_il_j+m_im_j+n_in_j\\&=\begin{cases}0 & \forall \ i\neq j\\ 1 & \forall \ i=j \end{cases}\end{align}\tag*{}$ i.e., we have *normal unit* vectors for equation of each plane.

The assumption above is equivalent to assuming $\mathcal{OO}^\mathrm T=\mathrm I_3$. Notice that:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{OO}^\mathrm T&=\begin{pmatrix}\Omega(1,1) &  & \\ \Omega(1,2) & \Omega(2,2)&  \\ \Omega(1,3) & \Omega(2,3) & \Omega(3,3)\end{pmatrix}\\&=\mathrm I_3\end{align}$$

**N.B.**: $\mathcal {OO}^\mathrm T$ is symmetric so I have omitted repeated entries.

Since $\mathcal {OO}^\mathrm T=\mathrm I_3$, we have that $\mathcal O$ is orthogonal. It follows that $\mathcal{O}^\mathrm T\mathcal O =\mathcal{OO}^\mathrm T =\mathrm I_3$.

$$\therefore \begin{align}\mathcal {O}^\mathrm T\mathcal{O} &=\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma l_i^2 & &\\ \Sigma l_im_i &\Sigma m_i^2&\\ \Sigma l_i n_i & \Sigma m_i n_i & \Sigma n_i^2\end{pmatrix}=\mathrm I_3\end{align}$$

Comparing corresponding entries, we have:
$$\begin{cases}\sum l_i^2=\sum m_i^2=\sum n_i^2=1\\ \\ \sum l_im_i=\sum m_in_i=\sum n_il_i=0\end{cases}$$ which was to be shown. $\blacksquare$

For a system of three mutually perpendicular planes, there's always a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix associated with it. :)

The fact about orthogonal matrices: if you pick two rows, multiply the corresponding elements and sum it up, it's

- either $0$ (if you picked different rows)
- or $1$ (if you picked the same row twice).

This result holds for columns too.